# Creating instance of custom class

Tags: haskell, graph, instance

I seem to get an error message when trying to create an instance of *IntegerGraph*. I do not understand the error message. Any tips?
Here's the code:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set


class IntGraph g where
  emptyG :: g
  ... (more constructors) 


type MyGraph n = (Map n (Set n))

instance IntGraph MyGraph where
```

Error message:

• Expecting one more argument to ‘MyGraph’
Expected a type, but ‘MyGraph’ has kind ‘* -> *’

• In the first argument of ‘IntGraph’, namely ‘MyGraph’
In the instance declaration for ‘IntGraph MyGraph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Haskell, just as term-level expressions have types, type-level expressions have "kinds".  Type expressions that have kind `*`, like `Bool`, `Int`, `Maybe [Char]`, and `MyGraph Char` represent types that have associated values of the type.  For example, you can construct a `MyGraph Char`, like `Map.fromList [('a', Set.fromList ['b','c'])] :: MyGraph Char`, which is how we know `MyGraph Char` must be of kind `*`.

In constrast, type-level expressions that have kind `* -> *`, like `MyGraph` and `Maybe` have no associated values.  There is no value of type `Maybe`, for example.  Instead, these type-level expressions must first be "applied" to a type of kind `*` to produce another type-level expression of kind `*`, representing a type that can have values.  For example, if we apply `Maybe` of kind `* -> *` to type `[Char]` of kind `*`, we get a new type `Maybe [Char]` of kind `*`.

If this is all new to you, you might find this [old Computer Science Stack Exchange answer of mine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/111442/107180) helpful.

Anyway, your type class `IntGraph` can only have instances `IntGraph g` when `g` is a type expression of kind `*`.  We can tell this is the case because your definition of `class IntGraph g` includes a method `emptyG` that returns a value of type `g`, meaning that `g` must be of kind `*`, the kind of type expressions representing types that have values.

When you try to define an instance `instance IntGraph MyGraph`, you are trying to define an instance for a type expression `MyGraph` of kind `* -> *`, and GHC doesn't like this.  It tells you that in the expression `instance IntGraph MyGraph`, it was expecting `MyGraph` to be a "type" (technically, a type expression of kind `*`), but it instead discovered that `MyGraph` was of kind `* -> *`.

You can fix this by defining instances for specific `MyGraph`s:

```
instance IntGraph (MyGraph Char) where
```

or a single instance for all possible `MyGraph a`s, but you do need to include that type variable `a` in the instance declaration, like so:

```
instance IntGraph (MyGraph a) where
```